# No results when running query

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

I've created a query that won't show any results if I have a statement with quotes above the ORDER BY statement but the ORDER BY statement will work if I remove the quotes in my WHERE query, but I need the where query.

For example:

```
WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = E.STUDENT_ID AND Z.STATE = 'New York' OR Z.STATE = 'MA'
ORDER BY Z.ZIP;
```

If I remove the `AND Z.STATE = 'New York' OR Z.STATE = 'MA'` it works

Comment: you need to use parenthesis WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = E.STUDENT_ID AND (Z.STATE = 'New York' OR Z.STATE = 'MA' ORDER BY Z.ZIP);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the order of operations rules in SQL, `AND` has higher *precedence* than `OR`, so your current `WHERE` clause is being interpreted as this:

```
WHERE (S.STUDENT_ID = E.STUDENT_ID AND Z.STATE = 'New York') OR Z.STATE = 'MA'
ORDER BY Z.ZIP;
```

So this would only be true if the student IDs match *and* the state is New York.  You probably intend the following:

```
WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = E.STUDENT_ID AND (Z.STATE = 'New York' OR Z.STATE = 'MA')
ORDER BY Z.ZIP;
```

One trick you could have used here to avoid this pitfall would be to use `WHERE IN (...)`:

```
WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = E.STUDENT_ID AND Z.STATE IN ('New York', 'MA')
ORDER BY Z.ZIP;
```

This avoids the need to even use parentheses, so you can't go wrong.

Comment: This only works if I put the ORDER BY on the same line, if I put it below the line it doesn't run

Comment: Are you sure your tool allows this?  It sound like maybe you are entering carriage return and the query is being evaluated then.

Comment: I've used ORDER BY on another line for other queries and it's worked fine, so I'm not quite sure why it isn't working for this query

Comment: sql developer doesn't care where the order by is - same line or next. SHOW US it not working